# There is an error in Angular when command ng serve showing module not found

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, module, adfs

`import { MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular/msal.interceptor';`

I have declared the module and no error in Vs code but in command prompt error is showing which is "module not found", but module manually checked, its there

How to fix it, what should I do

Answer (score 1):

Check if these steps help you to fix the issue:

1. Be sure to install the `msal-angular` module in your application using the below command:
   `npm install @azure/msal-angular --save`
2. If you have already installed the module, there is a possibility that the module is not compatible with your angular version. Make sure to use Angular 6 or above versions.

I have created a sample application and I was getting the same error as you have mentioned, and it got fixed after installing the `msal-angular` module in my application. I have Angular 15.1.4 version.

*Before installing the module:*

[image]

Later, I have installed the `msal-angular` module using `npm install @azure/msal-angular --save`and the error got fixed..
[image]

[image]

**Output:**
[image]